# How can I remove the last two numbers from a number that's a double before making it a string?

Tags: c#

I have this number in C#

```
Double a = 1.2345678
```

What I would like is for it to look like this after it's made into a string:

```
1.23456
```

Comment: `Math.Round(a,5).ToString()`

Comment: `a.ToString("0.00000");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert it to string.
for example the string is defined as S.
then apply this method:

```
S.Remove(S.Length -2);
```

Comment: While this works for `a = 1.2345678`, the results may be unexpected for `a = 1.5`. I would favour Mohamads solution posted as comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive that in many ways:

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RemovingLastTwoNumber
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Method 1.
            double number = 1.2345678;
            string numberInStringFormat = number.ToString();
            string TargetNumber = numberInStringFormat.Substring(0, numberInStringFormat.Length - 2);

            Console.WriteLine(number);
            Console.WriteLine(TargetNumber);

            // Method 2.
            string _TargetNumber = Math.Round(number, 5).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(_TargetNumber);

            // Method 3.
            var characters = number.ToString().ToArray();
            var __Characters = characters.Take(7);
            StringBuilder __targetNumber = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var character in __Characters)
            {
                __targetNumber.Append(character);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(__targetNumber);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or the simplest, `number.ToString("F5")`

Comment: Yes of course we can do that as well... @pinkfloydx33